# Unity. How to turn the player in the direction of movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

As you can see in this video, the object moves in any direction, but its model does not rotate in the direction of movement. How to fix it ??

Link to video

> https://youtu.be/n4FDFDlsXK4

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller = null;
    private Animator animator = null;
    private float speed = 5f;


    void Start()
    {
        controller = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = (transform.right * x) + (transform.forward * z);
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(move.z, move.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        if (x != 0 || z != 0) animator.SetTrigger("run");
        if (x == 0 && z == 0) animator.SetTrigger("idle");
    }
}
```

Comment: no code, its impossible to know what you did to make it turn or didnt do

Comment: try this instead: `Vector3 move = new Vector3(x, 0f, z);` `transform.forward = move;`
        `controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: things are good. you can create an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `transform.forward` and `transform.right` to make your move vector, just make it in world space. Then, you can set `transform.forward` to the move direction.

Also, as [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) mentioned below in a comment, you should

1. avoid using exact equality to compare floats. Instead use [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) or use your own threshold like below
2. avoid setting triggers every frame. instead you can use a flag to determine if you're already idle or already running, and only set the trigger if you're not already doing the thing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller = null;
    private Animator animator = null;
    private float speed = 5f;
    bool isIdle;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        isIdle = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(x, 0f, z);
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(move.z, move.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        if (move.magnitude > idleThreshold)
        {
            transform.forward = move;
            if (isIdle) 
            {
                animator.SetTrigger("run");
                isIdle = false;
            }
        } 
        else if (!isIdle)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("idle");
            isIdle = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You still shouldn't directly compare `float` values as in `if (x != 0 || z != 0)` and `if (x == 0 && z == 0)` ... in general questionable if you want to set a trigger **every frame** ... but besides that it should rather be `if(Mathf.Approxiamtely(x, 0) && Mathf.Approximately(z, 0)) { animator.SetTrigger("idle"); } else { animator.SetTrigger("run"); }` or directly `animator.SetTrigger(Mathf.Approxiamtely(x, 0) && Mathf.Approximately(z, 0) ? "idle" : "run");`

Comment: @derHugo Ah, that's what I get for copying and pasting the question's code without reading all of it. Great suggestions, I included them in the answer

Comment: tell me why the rotation angle is not saved. it is always reset to zero

Comment: @Саске I put the `transform.forward = move;` line into the idle check, and also changed how idle is determined